# Arrays and ranges in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am pretty much new to the vba. So, a simple question. In a worksheet I have cells filled with integers. Say, cells A1 to E1. I would like to store the data in an array and then to address to the specific values. Running the code below has an error "subscript out of range". What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
Sub bounds()

    Dim Arr() As Variant

    Arr = Range("A1:E1")

    Debug.Print Arr(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried Arr = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:E1")), but still the same mistake arises. Now trying to google further, but still nothing. Thanks Shai Rado!

Comment: `Debug.Print Arr(1, 1)`

Comment: Slai, thanks. This works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier alternative can be to enumerate the values as that works with multidimensional arrays too:

```
Dim arr(), v ' As Variant is optional

arr = [A1:E1]

For Each v in arr
    Debug.Print v
Next
```

Comment: This works! Thanks again. But here you create "v" as another array. And I am not sure if I'm getting the idea of array "v" being an argument of another array "arr"

Comment: v is a single value not array, and has to match the type of the array

Comment: Ok. Really appreciate your concern!

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below (if you want to use a 1-D array):

```
Sub bounds()

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    ' use transpose to read the range to 1-D array
    Arr = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range("A1:E1")))

    ' loop through all elements in array
    For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print "Arr index " & i & " value is " & Arr(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot for help! I have also found the way to address to each element by using two arguments in Arr instead of one.